# How to use max in with clause to get a single value and use this value in main query with null check

Tags: sql, oracle

I am unable to write this, please help. Below will give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
WITH monthly_data AS
  (SELECT MAX(some_date) latest_dt FROM monthly_data
  )
SELECT SUM(data)
FROM daily_data
WHERE (monthly_data.latest_dt IS NULL
OR daily_data.some_date      > monthly_data.latest_dt)
```

**table: monthly_data**

```
id     some_date
007    08-MAY-2018
```

**table: daily_data**
some_date       data

```
07-MAY-2018     1
08-MAY-2018     1
09-MAY-2018     1
```

**Expected result**

```
Case 1: 1 row exist in table monthly_data.
Query should return 1.

Case 2: No rows exist in table montly_data.
Query should return 3.
```

The joins in the above query is incorrect but basically written to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do. Also, when I say no rows exist in table monthly_data, it is simplified explanation. There are other conditions in the actual query that filter out the data.

This has to go in a procedure

**Edit**
Thanks to @D-Shih I'm in a much better position where I started by using the exist clause query that he has provided.

On performance terms, can we write it in a faster way? Something that can evaluate to below would be fastest I believe

```
WITH CTE AS
  ( SELECT MAX(some_date) latest_dt FROM monthly_data
  )
SELECT SUM(d.some_data)
FROM daily_data d
WHERE (d.some_date > '08-MAY-2018'
OR '08-MAY-2018'  IS NULL)
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?Your query make no sence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I've added more details

Comment: Thank you,I edit my answer you can try it. @Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct.I think this will be work.

Due to you didn't provide some sample data and expect result.If that didn't your expect result,you can provide some sample data and expect result,I will edit my answer.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Max(some_date) latest_dt 
    FROM   monthly_data
) 
SELECT Sum(d.data) 
FROM   daily_data d
WHERE Exists (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM CTE c
    WHERE  
        d.some_date > c.latest_dt 
    OR 
        c.latest_dt IS NULL 
)
```

**Edit**

You can try use `CTE` table  `JOIN` on `daily_data` table

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Max(some_date) latest_dt 
    FROM   monthly_data
) 
SELECT SUM(d.data)
FROM CTE c JOIN  daily_data d
ON  d.some_date > c.latest_dt OR c.latest_dt IS NULL;
```

*sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33c64e/28*

Comment: Thanks this works. But my daily_data table is huge (with index on some_date column). I feel that there should be a faster way to do this using some kind of join.

I compared the above query with the below (query with a hard coded value) and there is **BIG** difference in cost and running time.

`WITH CTE AS
  ( SELECT MAX(some_date) latest_dt FROM monthly_data
  )
SELECT SUM(d.some_data)
FROM daily_data d
WHERE (d.some_date > '08-MAY-2018'
OR '08-MAY-2018' IS NULL)`

In this case also with clause is evaluated.

Comment: @Nikhil I edit my `JOIN` version query sql,you can try it :)

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN md.Sdate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 
            SUM(CASE WHEN md.Sdate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        ELSE 
            SUM(CASE WHEN md.Sdate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        END cnt
FROM daily_data dd
LEFT JOIN monthly_data md ON md.Sdate = dd.Sdate
....... {other conditions}
```

Comment: You have joined the table monthly_data twice which I want to avoid. (It is not that this table will be empty. It will not return any rows based on other conditions that are not mentioned in the post for simplicity.

`SELECT COUNT(1) 
 FROM monthly_data 
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 1`

is actually below in real life

`SELECT COUNT(1) 
 FROM monthly_data 
 WHERE {lot of other conditions}
and ROWNUM <= 1`

Comment: How do we know about the conditions that you have if it is not mentioned in the question, you should mention all required conditions that is needed and it's not mandatory to provide less information to make question to easy to understand, or in your word simplicity.

Comment: Sorry about that :) But 1 table should never appear twice in a query :)